# How to use custom label during call of Lightning Component in VF Page

Tags: visualforce, lightning

I am trying to use custom label during call of a lightning component in Visualforce  Page. but its giving me blank value. can anyone please help me how i can do this,

CODE:

```
$Lightning.createComponent("c:AccSearchComponent",
    { 
      // Set Lightning Component Attributes Property before creating Lightning Component In Visualforce page 
        textColor : "Red",
        ObjectToQuery : "how to use CUSTOM LABEL HERE !!"                
    },
   "LcDisplayId",
    function(component) {
        // create component Callback, Lightning Component has been Created,
        // Now you can set more lightning Component attributes here,
        // and do more cool stuff here

    });
 });
```

Comment: have you tried invoking createComponent after you actually have a custom label value? are you unable to fetch the custom label value? what is the problem exactly?

Comment: Hi, I am using ObjectToQuery :  $Label.c.objName, but its not working. I think i am not using correct syntax.

Comment: @RAT__ That syntax is incorrect because you are in Visualforce, not in Lightning, and need to use the Visualforce syntax.

Answer (score 2):

It's not much different from any other Custom Label access in Visualforce. You'll need to use the [`$Label`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_label.htm#!) global in a Visualforce expression (`{! }`)
to obtain the Custom Label value. Since you're merging the value into JavaScript, you must also wrap the value in the `JSENCODE()` function to escape any special characters that might be present in the label value.

The Lightning Out context doesn't change this approach; the Lightning JavaScript isn't executed until it reaches the client, after the Visualforce markup is rendered on the server.